# Grid Data not visible

Tags: extjs4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/classic/theme-classic/resources/theme-classic-all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.2.0/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
        renderTo: 'helloWorldPanel',
        store:[
            {name:'Subhash Patel',email:'subh.patel121@gmail.com',phone:'8147349213'},
            {name:'Sanjeev Panjiyar',email:'Sanjeev.Panjiyar121@gmail.com',phone:'8157349213'},
            {name:'Subhash Patel',email:'subh.patel121@gmail.com',phone:'8147349213'},
            {name:'Sanjeev Panjiyar',email:'Sanjeev.Panjiyar121@gmail.com',phone:'8157349213'}
        ],
        columns:[
            {text:'Name', dataIndex:'name',flex:1},
            {text:'Email', dataIndex:'email',flex:1},
            {text:'Phone', dataIndex:'phone',flex:1},
        ],
        height: 400,
        width:600,
        title:'Grid Data',
        html:'<h1>Ext js Hello World Program</h1>'
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body color="black">
<div id="helloWorldPanel"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a store with memory proxy and assign that store to your grid.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var storeObj = {
        fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: 'array',
            data: [
                ['Subhash Patel', 'subh.patel121@gmail.com', '8147349213'],
                ['Sanjeev Panjiyar', 'Sanjeev.Panjiyar121@gmail.com', '8157349213'],
                ['Subhash Patel', 'subh.patel121@gmail.com', '8147349213']
            ]
        }
        };
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        store: storeObj,
        columns:[
            {text:'Name', dataIndex:'name',flex:1},
            {text:'Email', dataIndex:'email',flex:1},
            {text:'Phone', dataIndex:'phone',flex:1},
        ],
        height: 400,
        width:600,
        title:'Grid Data',
        html:'<h1>Ext js Hello World Program</h1>'
    });
    }
});
```

You can find working fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2uq6) for your example.